# How do I disable Ctrl+Alt+s to minimize a window?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

When I type Ctrl+Alt+s on a window, the body of the window rolls up. How can I disable this shortcut, that I want to use for another purpose in my emacs configuration?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change it in *System Settings → Keyboards → Shortcuts → Windows*.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in Ubuntu 12.04 with gome-shell. It is a known bug. One can try to work with `dconf-editor` here, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/175369/cannot-disable-ctrl-alt-d-in-gnome-shell

Comment: and in 20.04 it does not work either

Answer (score 9):

It works in Ubuntu 13.04 and 14.04 LTS.

Go to System-settings -> Keyboard *(menu)* -> Shortcuts *(button)* -> Windows *(tab)* and then select `Toggle-shaded-state` and press `backspace` to disable it, and close the window.

Comment: This cannot be reporduced in 18.04.  I get System-settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts

In the Keybaoard Shortcuts page are various sections, one of which is Windows... and while there are options like "Resize Window", "Toggle maximization state", etc... there is no "Toggle shaded state."

This is frustrating because I'm trying to use Intellij-Idea which has Ctrl-Alt-S hardcoded as the shortcut to its Settings...

Instead, I get cyclic "adjust window size" action of Ubuntu.

Comment: For ubuntu 18.04 use `dconf reset /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-shaded` to disable ctrl+alt+s. 
BTW I am not able to post this as answer cause of my low reputation...

Comment: @user1185087 your advice helped! You've got >100 rep, maybe now you could post it as a new answer?

Comment: @RobertK.Bell 101 rep seams not enough to add an answer :(

Answer (score 1):

When You're using Compiz, then goto CompizConfig Settings Manager -> General -> General Options -> Key Bindings -> Toggle Window Shaded -> Edit -> empty the shortcut s.

Answer (score 0):

In 18.04, I used dconf-editor to change
*/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-shaded*
 from
**['<Control><Alt>s']**
 to
**['<Control><Shift><Alt>s']** so that emacs will get my regex search keystroke, but I can still (will I ever?) rollup the window shade.

c.f. [ctrl + alt + S on ubuntu 18.04 triggers a screen size toggle but is not listed in keyboard settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1352037/ctrl-alt-s-on-ubuntu-18-04-triggers-a-screen-size-toggle-but-is-not-listed-i)