# How to disable the "roll up" / "shade" keyboard shortcut in Gnome 3 (after upgrading to 12.04)?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, gnome, window

I am using Gnome 3. After upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> was reclaimed for use in toggling the shaded state of a window.

I have checked the following places, and I haven't been able to find any instance of a keybinding set for toggling the shaded state.

- System Settings / Hardware / Keyboard / Shortcuts (as per [How do I disable Ctrl+Alt+s to minimize a window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74041/how-do-i-disable-ctrlalts-to-minimize-a-window))

  - I even tried setting a different shortcut. Made no difference.
- dconf-editor (now deprecated, from what I've found)
- gconf-editor/gsettings

What am I missing?

Comment: This [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175369/cannot-disable-ctrl-alt-d-in-gnome-shell) contains the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to set up a new shortcut for the toggle-shade feature, using dconf-editor. Follow these steps:

1. Install dconf-editor: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Open dconf-editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, enter `dconf-editor`)
3. Expand until the element: `org → gnome → desktop → wm → keybindings`.
4. Change the value for the key `toggle-shaded` to something less intrusive: `['<Control><Super>s']`

**UPDATE:** There is an easier way to do it that does not require dconf-editor:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded "['<Control><Super>s']"
```

**Edit from [Michael Fischer](https://askubuntu.com/users/458357/michael-fischer)**:
T
o disable the keybinding with gsettings, just use the value `['disabled']`

Example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded "['disabled']"
```

Answer (score 0):

the following:

CompizCompiz > General > General Options > Key Bindings > (At the bottom) Toggle Window Shaded

will work if you install gnome-fall back in ubuntu 12.04

see :- http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Precise#Install_a_classic_Gnome-appearing_User_Interface