# How do I disable Ctrl-Alt-D in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome

I am using gnome 3 and gnome-shell (not gnome classic) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with emacs.  I would like to use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> with emacs, however whenever I hit that keystroke, gnome intercepts it and hides all windows.

I have tried to disable it under Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation > Hide all normal windows.  It appears disabled there, but if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> all windows will still minimize.

My next step was to try and use `dconf-editor` to disable it under `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`, but I couldn't find any option for "hide all windows" (or anything similar) there.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I can only add that I have the very same problem, but I don't know a solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I figured out that the following worked in my case. First, instead of trying to disable the shortcut, give it a new key combination. I did this in `System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Layouts -> Options...`, but it's a known bug that these settings are not respected in Gnome Shell.

Additionally, use `dconf-editor` to give it the same key combination:

1. Open dconf-editor (Alt-F2, enter `dconf-editor`)
2. Expand until the element: `org → gnome → desktop → wm → keybindings`.
3. Change the value for the correct key (in your case, this should be `show-desktop`).

In my case, I wanted `C-M-s` be respected in Emacs, and not roll up the current window. So instead of trying to disable the shortcut by using brackets in dconf-editor, I gave `toggle-shaded` a new key combination: `['<Control><Super>s']`. And suddenly, `C-M-s` was available in Emacs. Hope this helps for you, too.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked for me: setting `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.show-desktop` to `['<Control><Super>D']`.

Answer (score 8):

To disable the keybinding with `gsettings`, just use the value `['disabled']`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded "['disabled']"
```

Answer (score 4):

I just hit this problem on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS trying to unset the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> binding for "toggle-shaded".  AFAIK, I'm running the out-of-the-box window config: GNOME3, Compiz, Metacity, Unity.

Both Compiz and Metacity bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, which REALLY threw me because I kept trying to edit the keybinding for compiz as a number of posts indicate (or rather `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`).  But this changed nothing that I could see, even after restarting X.

In frustration I tried to edit the Metacity keybindings, which succeeded immediately (no need to restart unity, compiz or X.)  Here's the command line:

```
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/window_keybindings/toggle_shaded
```

Check `$HOME/.gconf/apps/metacity/window_keybindings/%gconf.xml` for the changes.

I monitored changes to all files in my `$HOME` via `man:find` while trying the various config editors: `gnome-control-center`, `ccsm`, `dconf-editor`, `gconftool-2` to see what changed.

`dconf-editor` worked well for compiz.  My understanding is compiz and metacity work together to render the display but I don't know how.  And I think there are a number of pluggable window managers that work with compiz, so that may further complicate the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Also don't forget to check if you've activated the **Screenshot Window Sizer** extension in *GNOME Tweak Tool*. It maps the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to resize gnome windows in various 16:9 formats.