# How can I change or delete the shortcut to shade/roll up a window in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

Somehow the shortcut for shading/rolling up a window has been set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in my Ubuntu 20.04.

I don't need the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut for the shading action, since it clashes with the standard PyCharm shortcut for *Settings*. I have found this similar question, but it doesn't seem to work in 20.04: [How do I disable Ctrl+Alt+s to minimize a window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74041/how-do-i-disable-ctrlalts-to-minimize-a-window)

I also didn't find a way to change the shortcut using GNOME Tweaks.

So how can I change or delete the shortcut used to shade/roll up a window?

Comment: Is my answer OK after my edit?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog extremely. This surpassed my expectations. I wish everyone were as through. I am truly impressed.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toggle-shaded` shortcut is not enabled by default and is not accessible using *Keyboard Shortcuts*.

In order to reset it to its default setting (no shortcut), you can run the following `gsettings` command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded
```

There is also a graphical way to reset it using `dconf-editor`:

1. Install `dconf-editor` using:

   ```
   sudo apt install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Open dconf Editor.
3. Go to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-shaded`.
4. Enable *Use default value*.

   [image]